# jQuery - completion of multiple ajax-requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

in a `$.each()` I do a AJAX-request:

```
$.each(all, function(i,v) {                                 
    $.ajax({
        url: "/mycontroller/"+encodeURIComponent(v),
        success: function(data){ 
            $('#inner').append(data);
        }
    }); 
});
```

now I would like to show a message if every AJAX-request in the `$.each()` is complete. But how can I do this, As AJAX is asynchronous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With simple javascript you can do it in following way:

```
var counter = 0;
$.each(all, function(i,v) {                                 
    $.ajax({
        url: "/mycontroller/"+encodeURIComponent(v),
        success: function(data){ 
            $('#inner').append(data);
            counter++; //increment the counter
        },
        error: function(){
            counter++; //increment the counter
        },
        complete : function(){
            //check whether all requests been processed or not
            if(counter == all.length)
            {
                alert("All request processed");
            }
        }
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can utilize [`jQuery.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/). This method

> provides a way to execute callback functions based on zero or more objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous events.

```
var ajaxRequests = all.map(function(x) { 
    return $.ajax({
        url: "/mycontroller/"+encodeURIComponent(x),
        success: function(data){ 
            $('#inner').append(data);
    }
}); 
jQuery.when.apply(this, ajaxRequests).then(function() {
    // do what you want
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use async :false to make ajax request to be completed before the browser passes to other codes

```
$.each(all, function(i,v) {                                 
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: "/mycontroller/"+encodeURIComponent(v),
       data: row,    
       success: function(data){ 
          $('#inner').append(data);
         }
       error: function() {
       console.log("Error")
    }
  });   });
```